# Why was "Is there a specific verb for when a person goes “um” and “ah” while they are thinking what to say?" locked?

Tags: discussion

Why was this question:  [Is there a specific verb for when a person goes "um" and "ah" while they are thinking what to say?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/533256/is-there-a-specific-verb-for-when-a-person-goes-um-and-ah-while-they-are-thi/)

locked?

It should probably be closed as a dup of the linked question, but why would it be locked in the meantime? (I'm used to at least a comment on contentious or disruptive questions saying why they are being locked, but here I just see a bunch of answers of varying quality.)

Comment: The lock is about comments, not answers: *Comments on this question have been disabled, but it is still accepting new answers and other interactions.*

Comment: But again, why? It seems like a perfectly reasonable question.  If it managed to spawn a flood of inappropriate comments that would be useful to know.

Comment: @arp Right, that's why the question "is still accepting new answers and other interactions," just not comments.

Answer (score 6):

There were sixteen comments, all now deleted, thirteen of which garnered flags and most of which are reproduced in actual answers to the question.

The lock discourages similar contributions, and encourages people who may have germs of answers to expand them into real answers.